# Using maven's --also-make option in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

You can set several properties and configuration options in a Maven build within IntelliJ, but I haven't quite figured if you are able to specify options that are available on the command line such as --also-make or --also-make-dependents.

Is there a way to have those options used by Maven run configurations in Intellij?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a run/debug configuration by right-clicking any goal in the `Maven Projects` view, select `Create your-project[your-goal]` and from there you can add any command-line parameters (such as `--also-make`). Your configuration will be saved and accessible from a single click on the green arrow :).

Comment: That did it.  It appears as though right clicking a goal in the Maven Projects view overrode the command line I set in Maven Defaults but creating a new goal from my-project[goal] did indeed work.

Comment: I could create a new configuration for every module I need to build this way, but this is a little annoying. Isn't there a more elegant solution? A setting to change that applies everywhere or something?

Comment: There is also now a "Resolve Workspace artifacts" option in the run configuration dialog below the `Command line:` field, which appears to work as `--also-make` does. Now if they'd just make this a project-level setting for Maven in the main preferences that's honored when all phase/goal executions are run…

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat I felt your pain. Try my answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can put `--also-make` into [the per-project `.mvn/maven.config` file](https://maven.apache.org/configure.html) which sets command-line options to always apply.

In combination with IntelliJ's option to ["Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html) (which seems to be default when importing Maven projects these days), this gets building and running with the IDE's main buttons and menu items working. No more failures to resolve inter-module dependencies or [failing Enforcer](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/reactorModuleConvergence.html).

There may be undesirable side effects to always including `--also-make` but so far I haven't encountered them—in a multi-module project using the Reactor this way is just about always what I want, so it saves typing on the CLI too.

*Side note*: I still find @Bastien Jansen's answer useful for invoking other run-like Maven goals, like `spring-boot:run` with IDEA Community Edition which does not have the more first-class support for Spring Boot applications that Ultimate does.